# AWSToolkit in Intellij, environment variables not working

Tags: java, intellij-idea, aws-lambda, environment-variables

I have an AWS lambda function that I have written in java that needs to access environment variables. I can set them up on AWS and I can access the environment variables perfectly fine when it is deployed on AWS using the following line of code in the lambda function:

```
System.getenv("myVariable");
```

For developing locally, I put the same environment variables in the run configuration for the lambda. Unfortunately when I try to access the environment variables locally I just get null values.  I must be doing something wrong as I'm sure other people must be using environment variables.

Answer (score 3):

So of course after spending all day on it, 30 minutes after I post I figured out the answer.

It seems you can't just add the environment variables to the runtime configuration for the AWS lambda.  Instead, you also have to add it to the template.yaml as an environment variable.  Below is a sample template.yaml with three environment variables configured (myvariable1, myvariable2, myvariable3).  Hope this saves someone an entire day it took me to figure this out.

`

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: My test project.
Resources:
  MyAwesomeFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      FunctionName: MyAwesomeFunction
      Handler: com.lambda.MyAwesome
      Runtime: java11
      CodeUri: .
      Description: Does some really amazing things.
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 30
      Environment:
        Variables:
          myvariable1:
          myvariable2:
          myvariable3:
```

`